# Error parsing CSV 15 Rows In - Can't Figure Why - Neither Can My Friends

Tags: javascript, csv, google-sheets-api

I am creating an interactive on student loan defaults. I am pulling the CSV from google sheets and parsing it with some code I wrote. I do a state name check which becomes arrayName and I push the data to that states array.

15 rows in I get arrayName.push is not a function...yet it worked for the data prior and the data has not changed format or type.

I am going to include the brief snippet and the csv link. If you would like the whole code download from the github link.

Thanks,
Michael

```
//Load CSV from Google Docs
    function loadCSV() {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var data = xmlhttp.responseText.toString();
            dataArray = data.split(',');
            console.log('data length: '+dataArray.length);

            parseData(dataArray);
        }
    };
      xmlhttp.open("GET",'http://cors.io/?u=' + url);
      xmlhttp.send(null);

    };

    counter = 1;
    arrayName = '';

    function parseData(data){

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //Counter for doing statname check when it gets to new row
            if (counter === 1) {
                if (arrayName != data[i].toString().toLowerCase()) {
                    // Code for creating arrays will go here in future [...]
                    arrayName = data[i].toString().toLowerCase();
                    arrayName = eval(arrayName);
                    arrayName.push(data[i]);
                    counter++
                } else { counter++ }

            } else {
                arrayName.push(data[i]);
                counter++;
                if (counter === 14) { counter = 1; };
            }
            console.log(data[i]);
        };

        console.log(data);
        console.log(alabama);
    };

    loadCSV();
```

CSV

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n-XiUc1JdRZpAo-WDj6MleE6WcDDnZwqdbQk0rudbLw/pub?output=csv

Repo

https://github.com/mpaccione/Loan-Defaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `split(',')`, which splits on every ',' - including those between quotes (see line 15)

```
dataArray = data.split(',');
```

line 15:

```
"700 PELHAM ROAD, NORTH"
```

Comment: You sir have made my day :)

The fact that the code would parse more cells after it hit the comma kept me from realizing that was it.

Thank You

Comment: Glad I could help - enjoy your day :)